# System not start: Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device

Tags: 16.04, boot, 18.04

I updated Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 and the computer is no longer started. Shows the black screen with two lines of text:

```
Gave up waiting for suspend/resume device
/dev/sda5: clean, 654724/11321344 files, 11449255/45268224 blocks
```

I can log in with `[ctrl]+[alt]+[f2]` to tty2, but once validated with username and password I receive the message:

```
[...] Could not find key with description: [228ce0775a82ad3]
[...] Could not find valid key in user session keyring for sig specified in mount option: [228ce0775a82ad3]
[...] Error parsing options; rc = [-2]
```

I can start the graphical environment with `startx` and it seems that everything works correctly.

I tried several options I found on the network, but nothing worked. I have mainly done tests with the `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` file. Nothing.

Where can the problem be? How do I solve it?

Thanks,
Josep

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the heads up about using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>!

For me `startx` did not work, so I reinstalled my NVIDIA drivers following [this guide](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux). Here are the basic commands you need to run in a terminal:

1. Purge old drivers, if any.

   ```
   sudo apt --purge remove nvidia*
   ```
2. Install recommended drivers.

   ```
   sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
   ```
3. Reboot.

   ```
   reboot
   ```